# Change the url of my website page

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to change the *url* of my website page but am not finding the solution.

I have tried jquery code, and made changes in *.htaccess* but have been unable to figure it out.

I want change this url

> http://example.com/cheap-flight-to-?country=lagos

into

> http://example.com/cheap-flight-to-lagos

Is this possible?

Comment: what you have tried in `.htaccess` ?

Comment: You could utilize the [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule in your htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_RERUEST} /cheap-flight-to\.php\?country=([^&\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ cheap-flight-to-%1? [NC,R,L]
RewriteRule ^cheap-flight-to-([^/]+)/?$ cheap-flight-to.php?country=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: i put that code in htacces file but could not find results. should i do some changes in "<a href="http://test.myshaliza.uk/cheap-flight-to-.php?country='.$country.'">"